# mercurial hg POST to remote server with php

Tags: php, mercurial

I have an account at bitbucket, here is what i want to achieve.

```
ME --push--> bitbucket <--post--> server
```

server to bitbucket is fine.

I try to setup the POST URL like this

```
<?php `hg pull -u`;
```

in my server. Is this the correct way? i try to apply the back tick to execute the command.

Comment: I am a bit unsure what you're trying to do. Are you trying to *host* Mercurial using the `hg pull -u` command? So that it will accept incoming requests and pull (when the client pushes)?

Comment: im trying to do this, except i use bitbucket and hg http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/the-perfect-workflow-with-git-github-and-ssh/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing this with `system()` or `exec()`, simply because that's the standard operation procedure.

Comment: `<?php system("hg pull -u"); ` is it something like this?

Comment: Yes, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.system.php  Be aware that php works from the directory where the php script is located - if you want to checkout a repository somewhere else, you will have to do this by a parameter. Also make sure you have all the access rights with the webserver's user.